# makefile include path and include source

Tags: makefile, mingw

I am trying to learn how to compile using gcc/makefile
If I use the makefile below everything works.

```
all: 
    g++ .\src\hello.cpp -o helloworld
```

But What I would like is to specify the source folder and files.

```
INCLUDEPATHS= \
    -I".\src\"

CFLAGS= -Wall -g $(INCLUDEPATHS)

all: 
    helloworld
```

But that does not seem to work, the error I get is

```
make all 
make: *** No rule to make target `hello.exe', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

How do I change my makefile to have the include path defined?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense (and I can't reproduce it). Start with the makefile that doesn't work; what happens if you remove the `CFLAGS= ...` line?

Comment: If I create a makefile with the first block of code, all works fine. If I use the second block of code, I get the error I added.

Comment: If I remove `CFLAGS= ...`, then I get `make: helloworld: Command not found`

Comment: That makes sense. Now restore the `CFLAGS= ...` line, change `helloworld` to `@echo helloworld`, and change the `INCLUDEPATHS` assignment to `INCLUDEPATHS= foo`

Comment: Sorry, how is this going to help? `all: @echo helloworld` will achieve nothing, (apart from echoing "helloworld") and `INCLUDEPATHS= foo` will have no effect.

Comment: The idea is to find out what's wrong with the makefile; the changes I am suggesting will not give a working makefile, but they will give information about what is going wrong. The `@echo helloworld` will indicate that Make is executing the rule, and if the makefile with your current `INCLUDEPATHS=...` fails, but the makefile with `INCLUDEPATHS= foo` runs without error, then the problem is in your `INCLUDEPATHS` assignment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98603/discussion-between-simon-goodman-and-beta).